# How can I return a response in ExecuteBindingAsync and not continue execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, parameters

I'm using HttpParameterBinding to not only assign a value to a parameter on a webAPI action, but I'm also using it to check permissions.

```
public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //I get the userId from another parameter that is set from another parameter binding
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(actionContext.ActionArguments["userId"]);

            var permission = getPermissions(userId);
            if (permission < minRight)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Permission Denied.")
                };
            }

            actionContext.ActionArguments[Descriptor.ParameterName] = permission;

            var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            taskSource.SetResult(null);
            return taskSource.Task;
        }
```

However this continues on with execution. Is there a way, preferably without throwing an exception, to return a 401 response here and not continue execution.

Comment: but why are you doing permission check in ExecuteBindingAsync? I don't think it is meant for that. Why not using Authorization filter or Message Handler?

Comment: I get the userId from another parameter that is set from another parameter binding, that userId is then what is used for permissions. This is done to prevent doing some other calls twice. Ultimately though, this could be any response, including 500, if I don't like what's being bound. etc..

Comment: at the end, userID is coming in Request and you can fetch it from Request even before binding and perform necessary permission validation. Anyway, I don't see in webAPI pipeline (http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) that Binder is returning the response. It is only Action filter that executes after Binding that returns a response.

Comment: I see what you are saying and I could make another ActionFilter that would run after binding and validate there and return response there. So doing it the way of the question ask would prevent having to "chain" attributes so to speak, but may not be possible.